# How can i use fragment back button to go one step back?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am beginner in android and I am working on a small project.
There is multiple fragment in that and I'd like to add a back button in fragment to go back.

How can i do that?

Comment: Can you edit to include any steps you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

create a back button in your fragment layout, then get a reference of it in your fragment class as shown below.

```
Button backButton  = (Button)layout.findViewById(R.id.back_button);
backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getActivity().onBackPressed();
            }
        });
```